# Expressing "off the hook" in German

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

I am trying to express "get off the hook" correctly in German. In dictionaries, I see what seems to be two possibilities: "aus dem Schneider sein/kommen", and "vom Haken kommen/lassen". Let me provide a couple examples:

1. The criminal could have been sentenced to five years in prison, but he "got off the hook" with only one.
2. I was supposed to pay the dinner bill for the entire party, but I think I'm "off the hook" now.

Let me try a couple of translations:

1. Der Verbrecher konnte ein funfjärige Haftstrafe bekommen haben, aber ist mit nur einem Jahr aus dem Schneider gekommen.
2. Ich sollte die Rechnung für die ganze Partei bezaheln, aber ich glaube, ich bin aus dem Scheider gekommen.

Does "aus dem Schneider kommen" work here, or would "vom Haken sein/kommen" work better?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

> The criminal could have been sentenced to five years in prison, but he "got off the hook" with only one.

Der Straftäter hätte zu 5 Jahren Gefängnis verurteilt werden können, aber er **kam** mit nur einem Jahr **davon**.

There are several ways to express this. I chose *davonkommen* above, considering the serious nature of it. You could also say *aber er bekam nur ein Jahr*. I rather know *jemanden vom Haken lassen*, i. e. you need someone who does that, e. g. in this case a judge. The mental picture is that of a fish set free, which doesn't fit well when he still got 1 year in prison.

(Volker Landgraf added in a [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53369/expressing-off-the-hook-in-german#comment129775_53372) "mit einem blauen Auge davonkommen" which is also often used to elaborate a bit more. You can very well use it. Its literal meaning is that someone got away with a black eye (only)).

> I was supposed to pay the dinner bill for the entire party, but I think I'm "off the hook" now.

Ich sollte die Rechnung für die ganze Partei bezahlen, aber ich denke **ich bin** jetzt **aus dem Schneider**.

(Note: Maybe *Gesellschaft* depending on the context. *Partei* means a political party).

*Aus dem Schneider kommen* is unknown to me. It's *aus dem Schneider sein*. It can well be used if you have done something wrong and fear the consequences, but then someone else confesses and no one bothers you.

Again, there are several other ways to express it, I would probably drop the *Schneider* entirely and maybe say something like *aber das hat sich jetzt erledigt* (that the plan to let me pay is done with).

[LEO](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/off%20the%20hook) translates "(to let someone) off the hook" the following ways:

1. "jmdm. aus der Patsche helfen" (to help someone out of something)
2. "jmdn. aus der Verantwortung nehmen" (absolving someone from their responsibility)
3. "jmdm. verzeihen" (to pardon / forgive someone)

They don't really fit, but the *let* may be at fault here.

So I would suggest these possibilities

- *aus dem Schneider sein*
- *davonkommen*

Comment: In the example with the 5 years vs. 1 year sentence (still unpleasant but less than feared) you could use the term *mit einem blauen Auge davonkommen* (to get away with (nothing worse than) a black eye).